# Compute a window function on a data frame column

Tags: r, dplyr

I've written the code below to apply a weighted function to the `rand` column. The calculation for `rollsum_rand` has a nice and compact notation. Is there a similar way to do this for the `rollsum_rand_weighted` which would be more compact and extensible than the code below? For example, if I want to have the window be of length `10`, this would require a bit of manual re-coding and I would like to avoid that. If possible, I would like to stay with `dplyr` compatible code.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

weights <- exp(1:5) / exp(5)

 data.frame(rand = rnorm(5*20) ) %>% 
 mutate(rollsum_rand = rollsum(x = rand, 5, align = "right", fill = NA) ) %>% 
 mutate(rollsum_rand_weighted = weights[5] * rand + 
                                weights[4]  * lag(x=rand, n=1) +
                                weights[3]  * lag(x=rand, n=2) +
                                weights[2]  * lag(x=rand, n=3) +
                                weights[1]  * lag(x=rand, n=4) 
          )
```

This gives the result:

```
            rand rollsum_rand rollsum_rand_weighted
1   -0.270520763           NA                    NA
2   -0.630596660           NA                    NA
3    0.235524718           NA                    NA
4   -0.186220201           NA                    NA
5   -1.694303918  -2.54611682           -1.76728602
6    0.614248631  -1.66134743           -0.03407681
7    0.969988049  -0.06076272            0.96170082
8    0.279189752  -0.01709769            0.63139276
9   -0.009162437   0.15996008            0.22436872
10   0.395993700   2.25025770            0.48995047
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DF %>% mutate(weighted = rollapplyr(rand, 5, crossprod, weights, fill = NA))
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks! Which argument is `weights` for `rollapplyr`? I see it's the 5th argument (since DF would be the 1st). But how can I read the documentation and know which argument would be 5th when all after the 3rd (after `...`) are optional?  `rollapply(data, width, FUN, ..., by = 1, by.column = TRUE, 
    fill = if (na.pad) NA, na.pad = FALSE, partial = FALSE, 
    align = c("center", "left", "right"), coredata = TRUE)`

Comment: It works the same as any *apply function.  If the ... arguments don't have a name then they are used as the second and subsequent arguments of the function.  In this case `weights` is the second argument to `crossprod`, i.e. `y`.  Specifying it as `y = weights` would be  the same thing.